# How do I successfully connect and test the connection using Mongo DB Sync Driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am having issues connecting to MongoDB Atlas. I am following along with the tutorials provided by MongoDB but I can't get it working.

Driver: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.3/ (latest version)

I am using the following piece of code to connect to MongoDB:

```
ConnectionString mongoConn = new ConnectionString(
                "mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.xdibk.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retry" +
                "Writes=true&w=majority"
        );


 MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(mongoConn);
```

The above code works but does nothing except for displaying some info in the console

[image]

I didn't find that any useful so I turned it off using:

```
Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

Then I decided to test the connection by trying to insert a collection and see if anything actually gets saved:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("test");
Document document = new Document("title", "Test")
               .append("description", "Mongo DB connection and insertion test");

 collection.insertOne(document);
```

No errors but doesn't insert anything either.

I even tried putting all the code inside a `try-catch` but still no errors except when I remove the user or password it throws an exception telling me that password is required.

Apparently everything is working, my user and password are correct as well as the link to connect to MondoDB and I can't see what's wrong.

**The problem:** Everything seems to be set correctly but it doesn't appear to be connected and I can't see why it's not working.

**So my question is:**

How do I successfully connect to Mongo DB using MongoDB Driver Sync and how do I know it's connected as it doesn't give me any error?

Comment: Follow the docs you linked to more closely, also read about the [Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/). You specified `myFirstDatabase` as the auth database; you need to switch databases after connecting as described [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.3/driver/getting-started/quick-start/#access-a-database).  Typically you don't specify the auth database, the default `admin` is fine so leave that part off the connection string. `myFirstDatabase` would make a great test database for `myFirstCollection` however :)

Comment: Wow I can't believe I spent the whole day trying to do that...thank you very much. I think I got confused the connection string example MongoDB gave me when I cliclked on "Connect" there was "MyFirstDatabase" in the connection string I somehow thought that it was the database I was going to work on and not the auth database. Thank you again.

Comment: I've made that mistake myself so it was very familiar to me...glad I was able to help.  I've posted my comment as an answer for completeness; please accept if you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying your database as the authentication database.  According to the [Connection String URI Format page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) in the MongoDB reference the URI format is:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]
```

Typically `admin` is used as the authentication database so your `ConnectionString` would be:

```java
ConnectionString mongoConn = new ConnectionString(
    "mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.xdibk.mongodb.net/admin?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
```